# How to get Windows Desktop Search to Index URL Shortcuts

Tags: windows-desktop-search

I love Windows Desktop Search 4.0 (XP/32-bit).  I think that it's the best general piece of software since the GUI.  It indexes the content of my outlook emails, their attachments, pdfs, files and any other file I point it at.  I can search using all types of file critia (e.g. dates, authors, from:, to:, extension, filename, etc.)  [This](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23) is not the same program as the built in "Windows Search" tool, with the little dog.

EXCEPT URL (internet shortcut) files!? At least consistently.  Even though .URL extensions are enabled (Filter Description = "Favorites IFilter") and the shorcuts are in the folders flagged to be indexed, it won't even find internet shortcuts by name.

If I search "extension:url" it'll find 35 of the 400+ internet shortcuts that I have.  Sometimes it'll only find one of two urls in a single directory.

I have rebuilt my database.